# Wordpress: WP admin not reflecting changes

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to duplicate the main site and created a folder for the copied one in my cpanel. Then I deleted the wp_config.php file of the copied then on setup for the copied one I set the database details same as the main site and still set the prefix table to 'wp_' which is also the same as the main site.

Now that I've did that, I got logged in the wp admin but the url is the same as the main site, "main_url/wp-admin". Then when I logged out and went to the copied one which is like this main_url/copied_one_folder_name/wp-admin I get redirected to some url and trying to log in but I can't.

But I can still log in using the main_url/wp-admin but then making changes there doesn't reflect the main site anymore. Is it because I've used the same db and somehow the one controlling the db is now the copied one? How do I fix this? Please help.

Comment: You have to change all URL as per new server/link by SQL query , then only you will be able to access wp-admin with new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly change your Main URL to New URL in database using following query :

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

Above will solve your issue. Remember same database do not change URL as per new location when you import. So it is require to change all URLs using **UPDATE SQL Query**.

So In your case http://www.oldurl will be **main_url** & http://www.newurl will be **main_url/copied_one_folder_name**

Comment: I'm scared to try this. :( I don't want the new url. I want to revert back the database to the main_url. So somehow when I edit in main_url/wp-admin nothing changes in the main_url site..

Comment: this query you will need to run on new database of your new url , so do not worry , it will not affect your main url.

Comment: Ok I did all the queries above, the new url is now accessible also its admin, now somehow the two sites are now mixing.. It seems like they are accessing one database. But the new url is directing it all to main, only the homepage is working, but others are not existing so it redirect it to the main site. Oh no! What now? Can we skype bro?

Comment: Did you create new database for new URL?

Comment: Yes I created new database for the new URL. I exported the database of the main, and import it to the new database then I executed those 4 queries. Then the new URL works with wp-admin but only its link is working this one main_url/new_url_folder but other links like main_url/new_url_folder/our-story directs to main_url/our-story because it doesn't exist. Bro can we skype or anything so we could talk better?

Comment: It seems .htaccess is redirecting new  URLs to old I think. we can chat here.

Comment: So if that's the case, how to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96227/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-unspeakable).